# Nginx rtmp live viewers

Tags: nginx, streaming, live, rtmp

I am using nginx with the rtmp module and I was wondering is there a way to get the number of live viewers that are watching the streams.

Thank you in advanced for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at hlswatch: https://github.com/faryon93/hlswatch

I'm currently considering it for a project. I've never seen it work though, so no guarantees. It's the only thing I've seen like it, I figure most people must build their own system.